# XPATH: Node with text or any attribute with specific value

Tags: xpath

I am writing a code in C# where I need to find a child node based on a criteria and replace its value.

**What is available :**

1. XML Node
2. placeholder = string indicating placeholder
3. replacementString = placeholder string needs to be replaced with this string

**What is to be done :**

1. Find a child in the xml node with text = placeholder 
   or a node with any attribute havingvalue = placeholder string
2. if node, assign inner text = replacementString. 
   if attribute, replace attribute value with replacementString

**Progress so far :**

I am able to find a node with placeholder as text with xpath

```
descendant::*[text()='placeHolder']
```

But now I am stuck with addition of rule where placeholder can be present as attribute values too.

**Restriction:**

It needs to be accomplished in XPath that can be used in SelectSingleNode. It is assured that there can be one and only node/attribute with given placeholder

**Alternative:**

I know I can get string of the xmlnode, perform string replacement, load it in DOM and get the document element. But I do not want to create another DOM in memory just for the string replacement.

Thanks already

Comment: It would be good if you give me the `xml` sample, whereas I can provide you the needed `XPATH` expression.

Comment: @RubyLovely : That was the part of the problem as I would not know the structure of xml I am supposed to perform replacement on. The marked answer works for my purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given

```
XmlNode foo;
string placeHolder, replacement;
```

you should be able to use

```
XmlNode rep = foo.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//@*[. = '{0}'] | //text()[. = '{0}']", placeHolder));
if (rep != null) {
  rep.InnerText = replacement;
}
```

as both `XmlText` as well as `XmlAttribute` have a settable `InnerText` property.

[edit] If the node `foo` is part of a larger document then it is better to change the XPath to

```
XmlNode rep = foo.SelectSingleNode(string.Format(".//@*[. = '{0}'] | .//text()[. = '{0}']", placeHolder));
```